# selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException while invoking .click() on an element through expected_conditions

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Using python, chromedriver and Windows. 
I've working on a script for some months which uses .click() function regularly, few days ago it stopped working anywhere on the site. I've been trying to locate the element by id, xpath, etc... or even click it by `send_keys(Keys.ENTER)` with no success. I'm just trying to click the login icon but nothing happens. Seems to find the element and even click it, but nothing happens. This is [the site](https://es.wallapop.com/) and here the code:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'chromedriver.exe')

browser.get(('https://es.wallapop.com/'))

signInButton = WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'js-show-login-modal')))
signInButton.click()

signInButton = WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'btn-go-login-form')))
signInButton.click()
```

a part from not working this is what I get from the terminal:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wallapop_delete.py", line 55, in <module>
    signInButton = WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((B
y.ID, 'btn-go-login-form')))
  File "C:\Users\zaico\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\
selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

and this is what should happen on the browser:

-first click on the icon
[image]

-and after this should appear
[image]

Comment: Did you check for (browser)errors ?

Comment: what is your chrome and chrome driver version

Comment: What happens when you run this code? Does it open any of the popup modals?

Comment: @JeroenHeier what do yo mean by browser errors?

Comment: @Prany prior to last. But try it on the last too

Comment: @Jim added prompt to the question

Comment: @Zaico Could you add the output from `chromedriver --version`? I'm getting a different error when I run your code (`Message: unknown error: unknown sessionId`) but simply wrapping the `browser.get(...)` line with a try/except WebDriverException bypasses it and your code  seems to work fine.

Comment: @Zaico- I didn't get you, please add the version number of both chrome browser and chrome driver

Comment: @Prany Versión 67.0.3396.87 for the browser and 2.38.551601 for chromedriver

Comment: @DeliriousLettuce added images of what should happen on the browser to check if its working

Comment: have you tried increasing your `WebDriverWait` `wait` time higher than 5 seconds?

Comment: @Zaico Yes, I've seen those screens as your code worked with my old chromedriver (2.36?) with a try/except. I just upgraded my chromedriver to the latest (2.40?) and your code works without any modifications at all. Have you tried upgrading your chromedriver?

Comment: @Zaico - Please update your chromedriver to 2.40

Comment: thanks everyone. Now I'm having another problem related to the same issue. Should I open another question and close this as answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the *url* you have shared to click on the link with text as **Regístrate o inicia sesión** you can take help of either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `LINK_TEXT`
- `PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT`
- `CSS_SELECTOR`
- `XPATH`

Here is the sample code using `PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT`:

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
browser=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
browser.get("https://es.wallapop.com/")
WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, 'strate o inicia sesi'))).click()
```

Browser Snapshot:

[image: strate o inicia sesi]

Comment: thanks. The problem is once I login elements clicked once working aren't anymore. For instance if it tray to click on    ```WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/tsl-root/tsl-list/div/div/div/tsl-catalog-item[1]/div/div[2]/span[2]/span/button[4]'))).click()``` nothing happens, even no error