# Selenium Automation – Interaction issue

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am working on a bot capable of login into a webpage (`postmark.com`). To do that, I am using selenium and python. As it is right now my code is capable of accessing the webpage, clicking on the login tap, inserting the user name and password; however, when it comes to clicking on the Login tap (to access the account) I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Documents/Bot_Poshmark.py", line 20, in <module>
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(Log)).click()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

The bizarre think about this, is that sometimes (like 2 or 3) the same piece of code that I wrote, can complete all the steps. Here is my code (I am using a Raspberry Pi 4 for this)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.poshmark.com") #Open webpage
Log_Field=(By.XPATH, "//a[contains(text(),'Log in')]")
Email= (By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder='Username or Email']")
Pass= (By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder='Password']")
Log= (By.XPATH, "//button[@class='btn btn--primary']")

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(Log_Field)).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(Email)).send_keys("xxx@xx.com")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(Pass)).send_keys("123456")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(Log)).click()
```

Do anyone have an idea on why this is happening?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send a character sequence to the *Username or Email* and *Password*  field you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://poshmark.com/")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href='/login']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#login_form_username_email"))).send_keys("xxx@xx.com")
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input#login_form_password").send_keys("123456")
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.btn.blue.btn-primary").click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://poshmark.com/")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[text()='Log in']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='login_form_username_email']"))).send_keys("xxx@xx.com")
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='login_form_password']").send_keys("123456")
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='btn blue btn-primary']").click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### This usecase

In this usecase, the line:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(Log)).click()
```

was unable to identify the desired element within the desired time frame hence you faced *TimeoutException*.

However, from *TimeoutException* it will be tough to dig out the actual result of the failure.

---

### Solution

As a solution to know about the exact cause of the failure, you need to remove the [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) and replace the line of code with either:

- `find_element_by_class_name(name)`
- `find_element_by_css_selector(css_selector)`
- `find_element_by_id(id)`
- `find_element_by_link_text(link_text)`
- `find_element_by_name(name)`
- `find_element_by_partial_link_text(partial_link_text)`
- `find_element_by_tag_name(tag_name)`
- `find_element_by_xpath(xpath)`

If required you can slow down the search inducing waits through [`time.sleep(secs)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603847/how-to-sleep-webdriver-in-python-for-milliseconds/52607451#52607451) while debugging.

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException while invoking .click() on an element through expected_conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50843483/selenium-common-exceptions-timeoutexception-while-invoking-click-on-an-elemen/50853898#50853898)
- [ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible returns TimeoutException even when element is present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50853798/expectedconditions-elementisvisible-returns-timeoutexception-even-when-element-i/50855181#50855181)

Comment: Thank you for your response. The issue was solved using your advise. However I have a question regarding the xpath of the last object "//button[@class='btn blue btn-primary']" you added a different xpath. I used the inspector to double check this and the xpath that I get is "//button[@class='btn btn--primary']". Would mind telling me ho you arrived to yours?

Comment: @Perro My bad, I was able to narrow down to this issue much after I published my answer. I missed updating the answer. Your _xpath_ was a bit off. As you have used _xpath_, `btn btn--primary` wasn't the exact value but it was **`btn blue btn-primary`**

Comment: On another note, I'm aware there are some differences observed in the HTML as depicted by `Right Click` -> `Inspect` vs `ctrl`+`shift`+`I`. I would suggest the later approach. See the **Alternate Strategies** section in [Why XPath does not highlighted the yellow mark in Chrome84?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62945647/why-xpath-does-not-highlighted-the-yellow-mark-in-chrome84/63073849#63073849)

Comment: Once again thank you so much for your response and for the references.

Comment: I am having a new issue, with another portion of my code. Now I am getting the following error  `TypeError: _init_() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given` In order to understand the error, I read the two references suggested by you; however, I am not sure what is the nature of this error. If you don't mind would you mind telling me your thoughts and comments about it. Thank you